# git action/workflow is not running other than master/default branch?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

According to Github Action's official documentation  ([workflow events](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/reference/events-that-trigger-workflows#about-workflow-events)):

> 2. The .github/workflows directory in your repository is searched for workflow files at the associated commit SHA or Git ref. The workflow files must be present in that commit SHA or Git ref to be considered.
>    For example, if the event occurred on a particular repository branch, then the workflow files must be present in the repository on that branch.

Does than mean I have to make same changes to same workflow in both master/default branch and the particular repo branch ?

OR only update the workflow in the particular repo branch?

Answer (score 1):

The workflow being executed depends only on the workflow defined in that particular branch.

Answer (score 1):

This can be very confusing.  To avoid confusion, we need to distinguish between what *Git* actually does (not that much), and what *GitHub* will do in various "events" (a lot of things).

GitHub define many *events*, many of which have nothing at all to do with Git.  For instance, GitHub define events that occur when creating "issues" using the web interface or APIs.  A GitHub issue isn't a Git commit at all: it's an entry (or sequence of entries) in a database that is invisible to Git.

Each GitHub event has a different set of definitions, and refers to:

- the "webhook event payload" and "activity types": these are GitHub-only entities
- the `GITHUB_SHA`: this refers to a hash ID (a Git *OID* ) in a Git repository, typically a commit hash ID;
- The `GITHUB_REF`: this refers to a *reference name* in a Git repository, e.g., a branch name (but using the full spelling, i.e., `refs/heads/br` for branch `br`).

You must pore over that [giant table of everything](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows) to see the complete list.

#### At the Git level (in any repository clone—yours *or* on GitHub)

At the *Git* level, branches don't matter, only commits matter.  Either a commit has a file named `.github/workflows/something`, or it doesn't.  The commit is found by a commit hash ID, and that's what determines which commit we're looking at, and then that either has the file or doesn't.  If it has the file, that commit has the file with the contents it had at the time you (or whoever) made that commit.

Note that *every* commit in Git stores a *full snapshot of every file* (that Git knew about at the time you, or whoever, made the commit).  The files that Git knows about are the *tracked* files.  A file is tracked if and only if it's in Git's index and therefore will be in the *next* commit.  When you *check out* some commit (in order to do work and make a new commit), Git fills its index from the commit you checked out, so all the files that are in that commit are now tracked.  You do your work, use `git add` to update the index copies of files, use `git add` and/or `git rm` to add and/or remove files to/from Git's index (making them tracked or untracked), and then run `git commit` to make a new commit.  The snapshot you make now—in the new commit you make—has all (and exactly) those files that were in Git's index at the time you ran `git commit`.

#### During a connection between Git and GitHub

When *GitHub* receive one or more *new commits* via `git push`, GitHub will:

- first, inspect those commits to make sure there are no overly large files in them, for instance;
- then receive and inspect one or more *branch and/or tag name requests* as the last part of the `git push` operation:

  1. the person or program doing the push may ask to *set a branch name* to a commit hash ID, creating or updating that branch name;
  2. or, the one doing the push may ask to *delete a branch name*.

Item 1 occurs for, e.g., `git push origin mine:yours`, where I push commits as found in my (laptop) repository under the branch name `mine` but request that your GitHub repository set *its* branch name `yours`.  Item 2 occurs for `git push origin --delete yours`, where I've asked your GitHub repository to *delete* its branch name `yours`.

In case of a `git push`, GitHub will inspect and verify these final requests.  If the push *is* allowed, *and* a workflow is to be triggered, GitHub will *read the `.github/workflows/*.yml` files<sup>1</sup> *in* the commit hash ID that's part of the push request*.  That is, if I ran `git push origin mine:yours`, the request may have looked like this:

- Here's a new commit with hash ID `a123456...`, here's it's snapshot, etc.
- And now, if you will, please set your branch name `refs/heads/yours` to `a123456...`.

Assuming I'm *allowed* to set this branch name in your repository, GitHub's workflow detection will look for `.github/workflows/push` in commit `a123456...`, because that's the commit hash ID I asked to set.

As an exception, if I asked to *delete* `refs/heads/yours` (branch name `yours`), GitHub will look for `.github/workflows/*.yml` in the commit that is the tip of the default branch.  The reason to do this is that *deleting* the name `yours` means there's no longer any hash ID to use with this branch name: The branch name *provides* the hash ID, and the branch name is *being removed*.

Note that creating a new branch name with `git push` should trigger both the `create` event *and* the `push` event, and deleting a branch name with `git push` should trigger both the `delete` and `push` events as well.  (The same goes for tag creation and deletion.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It's not clear what GitHub do with files in `.github/workflows/` whose name does not end in `.yml`, nor whether they allow names like `.github/workflows/w1/foo.yml`.  I have not attempted this myself to see what, if anything, happens with such files.  The documentation shows only simple flat-namespace files ending with `.yml` and that's all I've ever seen used.

---

#### Putting this all together again

The trick here is to remember that, at the *Git* level, Git really only cares about hash IDs.  The hash ID of some commit lets Git find the *files that go with that commit*.  This hash ID (or `GITHUB_SHA` in the giant table) determines which *files* are in the commit.

Git*Hub* extract the selected commit (well, *inspect* it anyway) and look for the `.github/workflows/*.yml` files *in* that commit.  For each such file, they (GitHub) read it and execute the rules found therein, according to the event that triggered this reading-and-executing.

Since only push events can create *new commits*,<sup>2</sup> the only time you need to worry about this `GITHUB_SHA` being a *new and different commit* than the one you'd have had selected by some previous `GITHUB_SHA` is for `git push` events.  And, since a typical `git push` looks more like `git push origin somebranch`, the fact that the name in my laptop repository *could* differ from the name in your GitHub repository isn't particularly tricky.  If I use a different name in my repository, it's up to me, the guy doing the tricky thing, to know to use the right `on: push: branches: ...` things if I'm doing that.

---

<sup>2</sup>Well, push events, *or* any file creation done through the web interface.  I assume the latter shows up as a sort of faked-up push event, which is pretty straightforward to do and might even be how it's implemented internally in the first place.